# Emacs -- Timing execution of function calls in Emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for some assistance, please, to measure the time of a function call when using a `while` loop -- i.e., the clock should stop when the function throws done.  I found the following timer on the mailing list:  http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2008-06/msg00087.html

```
(defmacro measure-time (&rest body)
  "Measure the time it takes to evaluate BODY."
  `(let ((time (current-time)))
     ,@body
     (message "%.06f" (float-time (time-since time)))))
```

It's used like this:

```
(measure-time
  (dotimes (i 100000)
    (1+ 1)))
```

An example of how to use the timer macro with a `while` loop would be greatly appreciated.  I'm looking for the total time beginning from before the `while` loop commenced to the end when `done` is thrown.

```
(defun test ()
  (measure-time)
  (catch 'done
    (while t
      [*** do a bunch of stuff]
      (when (condition-satisfied-p)
        [*** STOP THE CLOCK AND PRINT TOTAL DURATION ***]
        (throw 'done nil) ))))
```

Comment: Notice that if `body` contains the symbol `time` you'll have unexpected results. You can avoid such variable capture by using `gensym`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly as per the example you've quoted. You literally wrap `(measure-time ... )` around the thing you're timing. The entirety of the `catch` expression, in your case.

Did you not try that?

Comment: Ah, yes, it works now.  I didn't realize it was a wrapper -- I had tried placing it at the beginning and at the ending, but not sandwich-ing the catch expression.  Thank you very much -- greatly appreciated!  :)

Answer (score 6):

BTW, this macro is called `benchmark-elapse` in Emacs, but it is not autoloaded, so you need to `(require 'benchmark)` before using it.